# DatabricksRunNowOperator to refer all values dynamically from Run Config in Airflow 2.2.2

Tags: databricks, airflow-2.x

I am trying to populate values for notebook_params with a dictionary; this dictionary needs to be from Airflow's UI' config parameter. However, When i tried to make

```
job_id=42


python_params = ["douglas adams", "42"]

spark_submit_params = ["--class", "org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi"]

notebook_run = DatabricksRunNowOperator(
    job_id=job_id,
    notebook_params={{dag_run.conf}},
# expecting a dictionary to come here. But it does not.
    python_params=python_params,
    spark_submit_params=spark_submit_params
)
```

Apart from this, I have tried to as below

1)
Task 1 Python Operator: It parses the dag_run.conf and pushes to XCom.
Task 2 DatabricksOperator: `notebook_params = {{ti.xcom_pull(taskid="previosutask" }}`

I am always getting string  in those field and unsure on how to make for loops as if
`{{k,v for k,v in dag_run.conf.items()}}`